# Performing Get requests for Facebook on Windows 8

Tags: c#, facebook

I have downloaded the Facebook SDK fine but there seems to be deprecated code on the tutorials section.

I want to do a get request on a users profile to return photos. From the tutorial they suggested something like this

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
dynamic me = client.Get("totten");
```

Thing is in the latest version I have that Get method does not exist for the FacebookClient class. I can't for the life of me find a clear and cut answer as to how to perform this simple request.

Any help would be great.

Comment: In the fact the error id get compiling that code is `Error 1 'Facebook.FacebookClient' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and no extension method 'Get' accepting a first argument of type 'Facebook.FacebookClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\MainPage.xaml.cs 60 33 TestApp
`

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't gotten this...you can assign a handler to client.GetCompleted and call client.GetAsync(). This is what I got from the example code --

```
    private void GraphApiSample()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);
        fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message));
                return;
            }
            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                ProfileName.Text = "Hi " + (string)result["name"];
                FirstName.Text = "First Name: " + (string)result["first_name"];
                FirstName.Text = "Last Name: " + (string)result["last_name"];
            });
        };
        fb.GetAsync("me"); 
    }
```